# How to change shortcuts for coverage navigation in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, code-coverage

In IntelliJ IDEA, when running tests with code coverage in tracing mode, you can see if lines are fully or just partially covered. Clicking on a fully or partially covered indicator, you can see which conditions are covered and which are not.

After doing so, it is not possible to move lines in code with the "Move Line Up"/"Move Line Down" shortcuts (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>) anymore. That is because the actions "Next Fully Covered" and "Previous Fully Covered" (depicted in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDuux.png) image) use the same shortcuts.

I can't happen to find these actions in the IntelliJ IDEA keymap settings. Is there any way to change the shortcuts for those coverage navigation actions?

Answer (score 1):

I've [reported a problem in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181127), please vote.

Answer (score 0):

Find Setting-Keymap  top-right Magnifying Glass

and press real key in "Find shortcut"

and change key

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, sadly those actions can't be found by this way.